# Does SpongyCastle support DERObject class?

Tags: android, certificate, bouncycastle, x509, spongycastle

I'm attempting to use the equivalent of the following class in an Android application, where I'm using Spongy Castle 1.54:

```
org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERObject
```

I cannot import `org.spongycastle.asn1.DERObject`, nor does the BouncyCastle API reference list `DERObject` under the deprecated classes list.

Does Spongy Castle simply not support this class?

Comment: That class has been removed from bouncycastle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In newer versions of **BouncyCastle** and **SpongyCastle**, the `DERObject` class no longer exists.

In **SpongyCastle** it was replaced by `org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive` (note that the [package name was also changed](https://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/)), and in **BouncyCastle** it was replaced by `org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive`

You can check what changed from older versions in [this link](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Porting+from+earlier+BC+releases+to+1.47+and+later), specially in the "**ASN.1 Changes**" section:

```
Old Class            New Class
ASN1Object           ASN1Primitive
ASN1Encodable        ASN1Object
DEREncodable         ASN1Encodable
DERObject            ASN1Primitive
DERString            ASN1String
DERObjectIdentifier  ASN1ObjectIdentifier
X509Name             X500Name
DERInteger           ASN1Integer
DEREnumerated        ASN1Enumerated
X509Attributes       X509AttributeIdentifiers
X509Extension        Extension
```